# HTTPS for mailto: in html

Tags: html, security, ssl, https

I would like for my page to have the green padlock signifying that it is secure. However, according to [https://www.whynopadlock.com/](http://www.whynopadlock.com) I need to change my mailto: form.

Here is my current HTML code:

```
                <form action="mailto:myemail@gmail.com" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="name" required />
                    <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email" class="email" type="email" required />
                    <textarea type="text" rows="4" name="Message" placeholder="Message" class="message" required></textarea>
                    <button class="res" type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
                    <input name="submit" class="butn" type="submit" value="»" />
                </form>
```

How can I change this code to make my site more secure?

Answer (score 3):

> However, according to https://www.whynopadlock.com/ I need to change my mailto: form.

I don't see any claim regarding `mailto:` links at the site you reference. 
And there is simply no HTTPS for `mailto:` links since writing a mail is done by a user specific application, which can be done a local mail client which is using SMTP for mail delivery (with or without TLS, depending on the settings of the client) or it can be done some web based mail application which might or might not be using HTTPS.

Apart from that using mail delivery to forward the data filled into a web form is probably not a good idea in the first place since it requires the user to have setup some mail application already - i.e. unusable for use with web kiosk, internet cafes etc. The common way is instead to have some backend at your site as form target, and this time you could use `https://`.